# Changing variable names in the middle of a function

Tags: c++, variables, rename, naming

Suppose I have some object with an initial name such as `quantities_of_widgets`.

```
std::vector<int> quantities_of_widgets = GetQuantities();
```

I then perform an operation on `quantities_of_widgets` in-place. The vector `quantities_of_widgets` no longer represents "a vector of some quantities of things called widgets".

```
PerformOperationInPlace(quantities_of_widgets);
```

After this operation, a more appropriate name for the variable would be `weights_of_widgets`. That would certainly make the code more readable.

I can "change" the name by moving `quantities_of_widgets` to a new vector `weights_of_widgets`. This is a terrible idea. The move isn't free, it messes with memory continuity, etc.

```
std::vector<int> weights_of_widgets = std::move(quantities_of_widgets);
```

I could also document the meaning of the variable in comments. I might write

```
std::vector<int> widgets = GetQuantities(); // widgets represents quantities
PerformOperationInPlace(widgets); // widgets represents weights
UseWeights(widgets);
```

However, comments are less permanent and less readable. It becomes more difficult to keep track of the meaning of variables over multiple lines of code. If `widgets` is used 20 lines down in the middle of a large expression, I'd have trouble documenting the meaning of the variable at that point.

```
SomeBigFunction(Func1(widgets, some_other_object_1), some_other_object_2);
```

I could try aliasing, but I want to make the old name invalid to help with maintainability. Is there a way to **change** the name of a variable with no run-time cost?

Comment: Moves are a lot less costly than you make it out to be.

Comment: Maybe wrap that vector into a `WidgetProperties` class with "setters" like `quantities()` (or constructors taking values with that meaning) and "getters" like `as_weights()`. Do you need the "quantities" later in the code?

Comment: That move you're proposing isn't good: Without knowing your intention to micro-optimize the variable naming, it will remain unclear what it means. I'd rather try to return a vector from `PerformOperationInPlace()` and optimize that part by re-using the vector it receives as input. That said, concerning your actual question, just name the variable `tmp`. That name is pretty meaningless, but it doesn't cause confusion when the meaning changes in between.

Answer (score 1):

Worrying about such small overhead is almost certainly not worth the effort in all but the most extreme scenarios. However, for the sake of completeness:

The only way to get truly overhead-free renaming of types with non-trivial destructors is via copy-elision.

In this context, you could make use of it via an immediately evaluated lambda and NRVO.

```cpp
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> GetQuantities(int v);
void PerformOperationInPlace(std::vector<int>&);
void UseWeights(const std::vector<int>&);

template<typename T>
T rename(T&& rhs) {
    return rhs;
}

void foo(int x) {
    std::vector<int> quantities_of_widgets = GetQuantities(x);
    PerformOperationInPlace(quantities_of_widgets);
    UseWeights(quantities_of_widgets);
}

void bar(int x) {
    std::vector<int> weights_of_widgets = [&]{
        std::vector<int> quantities_of_widgets = GetQuantities(x);
        PerformOperationInPlace(quantities_of_widgets);
        return quantities_of_widgets;
    }();
    UseWeights(weights_of_widgets);
}
```

`foo()` and `bar()` compile down to effectively the exact same final assembly: (see on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/7bzPWexaM))

The only limitation is that the variable that will be renamed has to be declared within the lambda. Beyond that, implicit capture by reference makes the lambda effectively the same thing as a scope.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to document code by itself. Comments have tendency do degrade.
So I would do this this way:

```cpp
// name of this function terrible, it should be more like
// ExtractWeightsOfWidgetsFrom or something similar
std::vector<int> OperationInPlace(std::vector<int> data) {
    // note argument is a copy!
    ....
    return data;
}

void someCode() {
    auto quantities_of_widgets = GetQuantities();

     ...
    auto weights_of_widgets = PerformOperationInPlace(std::move(quantities_of_widgets));
    // here `quantities_of_widgets` is empty since contents has been moved
    // many tools will report an error if you use this value after that point
    ....
}
```

or even better I would just extract more functions:

```cpp
void someCode() {
    auto quantities_of_widgets = GetQuantities();

     ...
    ProcesWeightsOfWidgets(
        PerformOperationInPlace(std::move(quantities_of_widgets));
    // in this version someCode ends here
}
```

Comment: This is how I would tackle this as well. The only "overhead" compared to the original code is a single extra invocation of a 0-sized `std::vector`'s destructor. It's really not much at all, and could even theoretically be optimized away (though no compiler seems to do it as of today)